# How can I create separate/independent interactive zones in flash/animate?

Tags: flash, cs3

I would like to create a game then split the screen in two, three or four sections and have that game instance appear in each "section".  The game will then be independently played by the number of players corresponding to the sections.

Thanks

Comment: Export the game as swf... then in a "controller app" just re-load same swf multiple times for each needed instace.

Comment: I did that however the touch is "off" when I rotate the swf 180 degrees?